# Get the First Day of Current Week based on a given date variable

Tags: sql, function, datetime

How do I get the current week range in SQL based on a given date? Currently using the following query which provides an incorrect resultset.

```
Declare @dt date = '1994-08-27'
SELECT [start_of_week] = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, @dt, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), @dt);
```

Please check the image for details of expected result set:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first day of current week, try this :

```
DECLARE @dt DATE = '1994-08-27'
SET @StartOfWeek = DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, @dt), 0)
```

Information : the first day of the week for 1994-08-27 is 1994-08-22.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the day of the week and use that to go back to the day you want (in this example Sunday).

In MySQL dialect that looks like:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY);
```

Sunday is day 1, so that is why the -1 is there. NOW() is just right now, so you can replace that with your own date easily.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But I am having same issues as the resultset does not provide information for current week.

Comment: Ah, sorry: The function gives the "start of week". You can just apply the WEEK() function to get the WEEK. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html for all the available functions